# How do I iterate though string, create grid of JLabels depending on the character

Tags: swing, multidimensional-array, icons, iteration, jlabel

Hi Guys I want to iterate through the string parameter and for each character in the string I want to create a label with the icon that matches that specific character in the string. I want to the labels to be in a 5x5 grid.

I know that this code would just make a grid full of the first character but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to do which iterating.

```
public void makeGrid(String text){
    JLabel[][] labels = new JLabel[5][5];
    ImageIcon picToUse = null;

    for (int x = 0; x < text.length(); x++){
        char c = text.charAt(x);
        if (c == 'X') {// can't see
            picToUse = OuterWall;
        } else if (c == '#') {// wall
            picToUse = Wall;
        } else if (c == '.') {// floor
            picToUse = Floor;
        } else if (c == 'G') {// gold
            picToUse = Gold;
        } else if (c == 'E') {// exit
            picToUse = Exit;
        } else if (c == 'S') {// sword
            picToUse = Sword;
        } else if (c == 'A') {// armour
            picToUse = Armor;
        } else if (c == 'L') {// lantern
            picToUse = Lantern;
        } else if (c == 'H') {// health
            picToUse = Health;
        }
    }    

    JLabel[][] displayLabels = new JLabel[5][5];
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i <= 4; i++, k = k + 80) {
        for (int j = 0, l = 0; j <= 4; j++, l = l + 80) {
            displayLabels[i][j] = new JLabel(picToUse,JLabel.CENTER);
            displayLabels[i][j].setBounds(l, k, 85, 85);
            displayPanel.add(displayLabels[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make the `picToUse` variable into a 5x5 array as well.

Assuming that your string has length 25 (one for each cell of your array), you get the following:

```
ImageIcon[][] picToUse = new ImageIcon[5][5];
...
for (int x = 0; x < text.length(); x++){
    char c = text.charAt(x);
    if (c == 'X') {// can't see
        picToUse[x/5][x%5] = OuterWall;
    } else ...
}
```

Because of integer arithmetic, the range `[0,25)` gets transformed into `[0,5)x[0,5)`.

You can add the images to your label using

```
displayLabels[i][j] = new JLabel(picToUse[i][j], JLabel.CENTER);
```

Comment: but how do i make them JLabels in a grid? or do i not need to?